# How can sending a message to a dialog cause a "Stack is empty" exception?

Tags: autofac, botframework

My (non-Luis) bot app, hosted on Azure, has a RootDialog which handles all incoming activities that aren't simple commands that could be handled directly in MessagesController.Post, thus:

```
var dialog = scope.Resolve<IDialog<object>>();
await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => dialog);
```

RootDialog implements `IDialog<object>`, and is registered as such with Autofac. It is resolved in a standard Conversation.Container lifetime scope.

I also have a WebJob, whose job it is to occasionally reset the stack (kill any currently active dialogs) and start a new dialog, which may itself call other dialogs. Let's call them `DialogProactive:IDialog<object>` and `DialogChild:IDialog<bool>`.

First, the stack is reset. 'message' is obtained from a ResumptionCookie saved in the database.

```
using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))
{
    var botData = scope.Resolve<IBotData>();
    await botData.LoadAsync(default(CancellationToken));
    var stack = scope.Resolve<IDialogStack>();
    stack.Reset();
    await botData.FlushAsync(default(CancellationToken));
    await userInfo.ResetUserStateDBAsync();
}
```

and then a dialog is initiated by the bot:

```
using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))
{
     var botData = scope.Resolve<IBotData>();
     await botData.LoadAsync(default(CancellationToken));

     var stack = scope.Resolve<IDialogTask>();
     IDialog<object> dialog = null;

     dialog = scope.ResolveNamed<IDialog<object>>("ProactiveDialog",
                                        new NamedParameter("Param1", p1),
                                        new NamedParameter("dialogName", "DialogChild));

     stack.Call(dialog.Void<object, IMessageActivity>(), null);
     await stack.PollAsync(CancellationToken.None);
     await botData.FlushAsync(CancellationToken.None);
 }
```

ProactiveDialogA resolves an `IComponentContext` and goes on to resolve and call a DialogChild in its own StartAsync:

```
....
context.Call(newDialogChild, this.DialogDone);
```

This DialogChild calls `context.Done(true)`, and so ProactiveDialog's `DialogDone` is automatically called with the 'true' result. It itself calls `context.Done(null)` and everything is finished.

But the next time a user sends a message to the bot, the RootDialog attempts to handle it (see above at the very start of this question), and `Conversation.SendAsync(...)` fails with an InvalidOperationException - Stack is empty (and so the user sees a 'Sorry, my bot code is having an issue.')

It's fine after that - I presume some kind of internal reset happens.

Why is this? I thought we would be back to the start point, and a new RootDialog would be created and put on the empty stack. Why this exception?

Is it something to do with the ResumptionCookie used in the WebJob not being in sync with the later interaction after the bot-initiated dialogs are finished?

Using 3.5.3. Thanks.

Comment: Could the problem be where I'm creating and storing the ResumptionCookie? It is possible it is created and saved in the context of a RootDialog. If so, that might explain the stack frame disparity. Should I always be creating it at MessagesController.Post level instead?

Comment: It could be for many reasons. Like unbalanced wait operators or an authorization entry that is missing. Can you copy and paste the full exception error that your bot shows?

Comment: Thanks Fracisco. Here you go: http://pastebin.com/TXtg9EZd

Comment: Part of the problem is my poor understanding of how the ResumptionCookie works - I assume it's not actually a snapshot of dialog and dialog state, but just a pointer to a particular point in the stack. Even then I could be wrong. Basically, if I obtain an Autofac scope based on the saved ResumptionCookie, do a stack.Reset(), then a stack.Call(dialog.Void(...), which returns eventually, and my MessagesController's Post method sends everything to a Conversation.SendAsync(...RootDialog...) - where am I going wrong with my ResumptionCookie?

Comment: While ResumptionCookie should work fine it will soon be obsolete and replaced by ConversationReference:  https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/07f3e894fd15f96c124f89953e491aa2d150090a/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Shared/ConversationReferenceEx.cs#L5 Why don't you try this one instead and see if it works for you?

Comment: I noticed that in the new release. Thanks. I intend to give it a try. A shame the documentation and sample code struggles to keep up such is the pace of change in the BotFramework core development work.

Comment: Used ConversationReference, but made no difference to the exception behaviour. Still trying to figure it out, especially what is actually happening in the MessagesController when a RootDialog is resolved in the context of the latest Activity, and Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => dialog) is called. Why is the blooming stack out of sync?? One day, one day.

Comment: Does a ConversationReference refer to a 'freezeframe' in a dialog stack, including user/conversation data, or just to a point in a stack with no data, or is it just user/bot/channel identification? You have to guess this stuff with BotFramework.

Comment: Where you able to solve it? am having the same issue.